# The width and height of the plane does not correlate with the displayed units

Tags: units, scale

I cannot figure out how the blender unit is working. The width and height of the plane does not correlate with the displayed units. How is this possible ?
Here is a screenshot of my work.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finnaly found the solution : this is due to an icorrect scaling of the object. I did not act on the vertices of the mesh, but i scaled the object in edit mode.

[image]